# How to place a div right below another div?

Tags: html, css

The HTML is:

```
<div class="first">
    This is first div. This is first div
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    end
</div>
<div class="second">
    Second starts after first</br>When page is scrolled.
</div>
```

CSS part is:

```
.first {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    color:#fff;
}
.second {
    background-color:#F00;
    opacity:1;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
}
```

I want the second div to be placed after the first one. The first `<div>` would take up full height. That's the reason I have used `position: absolute`.

Also, I don't want to write something like `top:600px;` in second `div's` CSS, because when the window height reduces, white space is introduced between the two `divs`.

How to I make it start right after the first div, whatever the screen resolution?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v8xUL/457/

Comment: Remove position absolute!!

Comment: Then `left:0;` won't work. @Aaron

Comment: @Nivedita Why do you need `position: absolute`?

Comment: you don't need `left: 0;` a div will always be `left: 0` unless other wise specified.

Comment: There is a white margin. I don't want that. @Aaron

Comment: then remove the margin from the body tag?? ive updated my answer

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Then simply do margin: 0;
Btw, you're using things like: top: 0px;
But when something is 0 then you don;t have to specify the units (you may omit the px).

Comment: You should just remove all this positionning and dimensionning stuff. HTML&CSS laredy does that pretty well for you by default.

Comment: @Nivedita Are you looking for something like taking up the whole screen height? If so, have a look at my answer.

Comment: Yes exactly @PraveenKumar

Comment: reason for downvotes ?

Comment: @Paulie_D yes I know, I just wanted to remove the spaces. As this is a simplified version of a complex webpage, where bootstrap containers, rows, columns are used. So I had to mention `top:0` and `left:0;` since I cannot make all the margins zero.

Comment: @Nivedita First your question would look blank to anyone, as why the reason of `position: absolute`. You may as well add *I am trying to set the full height of the div*, which makes more sense. I have voted up and will make the necessary edit, if you wish.

Comment: @PraveenKumar okay you can edit the question. Thanks :)

Comment: @Nivedita Check it out! `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to make the two divs appear full height and also they should be next to each other, you need to set the `height` of the previous div (`100%`) as the next div's `top`. You need to give `top: 100%` for your second div instead. Check this out:

```css
.first {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-color:#000;
  opacity:0.5;
  color:#fff;
}
.second {
  background-color:#F00;
  opacity:1;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:600px;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  This is first div. This is first div
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  end
</div>
<div class="second">
  Second starts after first</br>When page is scrolled.
</div>
```

Comment: Worked :D Thanks .. :D

Comment: @Nivedita Guessed, because when you are using `position: absolute` for this, it should be for making it occupy the full height.

Comment: @Nivedita Make sure you give `<br />` instead of `</br>`, as the latter is wrong.

Comment: No .. But I know how to install  :P

Comment: umm.. I don't use twitter ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute;` 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8xUL/460/)

```css
body{margin:0;}
.first {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    color:#fff;
}
.second {
    background-color:#F00;
    opacity:1;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
    This is first div. This is first div
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    end
</div>
<div class="second">
    Second starts after first<br />When page is scrolled.
</div>
```

And it's either `<br>` or `<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position: absolute;`

```css
body {margin: 0;}
.first {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    color:#fff;
}
.second {
    background-color:#F00;
    opacity:1;
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
    This is first div. This is first div
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    end
</div>
<div class="second">
    Second starts after first</br>When page is scrolled.
</div>
```

Comment: OKay, possible reaosn for downvote, this doesn't work, because OP wants to use `100%` height. Check out my answer. `:)`

Comment: If the OP specified that to the question, then I would suggest that you're correct.

Comment: I am doing it. Ha ha. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Have a look at the question.

Comment: Great if only you'd have asked the question to begin with @PraveenKumar

Comment: Ha ha... Why should I ask man, I don't have that question. LoL. Anyway, nice answer for you too! `:)`

Comment: @Aaron I thought that would be an obvious reason for using height:100%.  Sorry.. I ll try to make my questions more clear.

Comment: @Nivedita, from your comment above you wanted to get rid of the margin created by the body tag? I'm not sure you knew what you wanted to ask.

Comment: @Aaron "This is a simplified version of a complex webpage, where bootstrap containers, rows, columns are used. So I had to mention top:0 and left:0; since I cannot make all the margins zero." I mentioned this in a comment above.